# Submit form on one server, process it and then post results to another domain

Tags: php, forms

I have a form on one page with the action set to /process.php

Within the process.php I have the validation of the form and also it writes to a database on the server it sits on.

What I'd like to do after it has written to the database, is post the variables to another domain that will then process those variables differently.

Comment: You want to user to redirected to the new server as well? In case not , I guess `curl` can be the answer.

Comment: Could you provide an example please. What do you mean with `another domain` and what will happen there? Will you wait for response from there?

Comment: What have you tried? I'd start with [`curl`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)...

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I have the form all working on my domain (http://www.domain1.com) but do not know how to post the results after to the second domain http://www.domain2.com are there any tutorials out there on CURL I can have a look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use file_get_contents for the same.

Example:

```
$name="foobar";
$messge="blabla";

$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'name' => $name,
        'message' => $message
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = @file_get_contents('http://yourdomain.com/process_request.php', false, $context);

 if($http_response_header[0]=="HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"):

            echo "iam 404";

 elseif($http_response_header[0]=="HTTP/1.1 200 OK"):

            echo "iam 200";

 else:

            echo "unknown error"; 

 endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works. Is there a way to receive what status is posted by from the receiving server? IE 200, 500 etc?

Comment: with @ symbol you can supress error.`code` $result = @ file_get_contents('http://yourdomain.com/process_request.php', false, $context);  and check the status with the result if($result=="FALSE"): handle error else: handle return value endif;

Comment: or you can use "$http_response_header". <br/>http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Comment: Could you kindly update your code to include the error handling?

Answer (score 1):

Example using curl:

```
$name = 'Test';
$email = 'test@gmail.com';

$ch = curl_init(); // initialize curl handle
$url = "http://domain2.com/process.php"; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); // times out after 10s
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // set POST method
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "text=$name&name=$email"); // post fields
$data = curl_exec($ch); // run the whole process
curl_close($ch);
```

Example without curl: http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/

Comment: So the post fields, would it accept variables that have been set right at the beginning, for example $name, $email etc

Comment: This CURL will send post to domain2.com/process.php.