# Pass array from one server to another

Tags: php, json

I have an array that stores user login information on www.website1.com.
When the user logs in on www.website1.com, I need to send the user to www.website2.com along with their information (user_name, password, etc..) in the array.

**This is the array that gets set on www.website1.com**

```
$user = [
"user_name"=>$_POST["user_name"],
"user_pass"=>$_POST["user_pass"],
"from"=>$result["domain_id"]
];
```

Comment: Why was this down voted? Can someone tell me how else I could have worded this, so I can...

Comment: What do you mean by `pass from one server to the other`?

Comment: I'm going to re edit the question.

Comment: you need add php files, the user must login and save some session variables and use jSON to print the user's account. 
After that go to your next server and get/load the php file from the previous server, or if the user never login then provide him a link to login to the previous server..

Comment: @ChowKiko any pages you can link me to for tutorials on how to do this? Or can you provide an example?

Comment: Use `serialize` or `json_encode`, and then use the `curl` extension to send a request to the server. Alternatively, if you have access to the server's file system then you can use most of the file system functions, providing the appropriate `$context` argument.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I wont have access to www.website2.com file system.

Comment: @ChristianDaley Olsen is right, you need to use cURL to access another server...
this might help you a bit: http://drupal.org/node/305799

Comment: @ChowKiko I think this is what I'm looking for. I see what's going on, but one thing. What purpose does `$result = curl_exec($ch);` serve on that page? The array `$data` would be my array above, correct?

Comment: the curl_exec is where if the process really works, the $data array is where the data processes comes in, like $_GET,$_POST,$_REQUEST, while in cURL its different, and curl_exec will help you to join between to servers by using the api_key and sessionid...mostly they are using cURL for jSON to load a certain PHP from other server

Comment: I think where I'm lost is how to I display the array once I'm on website2.com?

Comment: ok i'll give you a full code, but i am not promising that should be working..but almost there, and you are the only one who can solve it...

Comment: If the two websites are coordinated, then you can communicate on the backend, in a secure fashion. Ie, common database or encrypted back-end API. The user would be provided with a one-time use token included in a redirect of the user to the other website, which would load a webpage form that pre-populates.

Because this is information involving account credentials, having it pass via Javascript or other client-side means is a wholly bad idea, as it is subject to interception.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a form with action pointing to the url you want to redirect the user. Include the data you want to send in form inputs. Finally send the form. This can be done using javascript without any user effort required.

Comment: I had thought of that. But not sure that will be secure.

Comment: Sending passwords over the Internet is not. The whole scenario is somewhat extraodrinary and could use some replanning.

Comment: I think a form using POST process needs to use a cURL as well, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939156/submit-form-on-one-server-process-it-and-then-post-results-to-another-domain

Comment: @ChowKiko, what would I type on www.website2.com to get the values? `$_POST['name']` would have the values using a POST request already?

Comment: GET would not need that but that's far from secure if there's any confientiality in the data.

Answer (score 0):

**First Server(www.website1.com):index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$api_key = "ChowKiKo";
//First Server: index.php
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
            //-----------Server2 Validation--------------
        //Validate if the Server2's api_key is the same as my api_key
        if(isset($_POST['api_key']) && $_POST['api_key'] == $api_key) {
            //lets use methoding
            if(isset($_POST['method']) && $_POST['method'] == 'getUserInfo') {
                switch($_POST['method']) {
                    case 'getUserInfo':
                        $arr = array('username' => $_POST['username'], 'password' => $_POST['password'], 'from' => "http://www.website2.com");
                        echo json_encode($arr);
                        break;
                    case 'getUserPost':
                        //mysql_query()...[code here and echo the value]
                        break;
                    case 'getUserFriends':
                        //the same thing here
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }else {
        ?>
        <html>
            <head>Sample jSON with cURL</head>
            <body>
                <!-- Login Options -->
                <form method="post" action="index.php">
                    <input type="text" name="username" />[...]
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

**Second Server(www.website2.com):index.php**

```
<?php
//Second Server: index.php

      $api_key = 'ChowKiKo'; // Your API key.
      $server1 = 'http://www.website1.com'
      //$sessid = '9999your9999sess9999id'; // Your session ID.

      //starting cURL
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $server1);

      //prepare the field values being posted to the service
      $data = array(
        'method' => '"getUserInfo"', 
        'api_key' => '"'. $api_key .'"', 
        //'sessid' => '"'. $sessid .'"', 
        //'arg1' => '"some value"', 
        //'arg2' => '"somevalue"', 
        //'argN'=>'"another value"',
      );

      // POSTFIELD like GET process but processing internally with www.website1.com/index.php?method=getUserInfo&api_key=ChowKiko
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

      //make the request
      $result = curl_exec($ch);

      //print the jSON of the Server1, else it will return false.
      echo $result;
?>
```