# Post form data to foreign aspx form

Tags: php, html, mysql, asp.net, forms

im trying to use a html/php form (my own) to submit data to a foreign form. The foreign form is a mixture of html, php, js and aspx (aspx is the thing i have no idea of).

Its a registration form for a raffle, our company works with them and we are doing a joint raffle. So we want to data from the people, who join our raffle (Our html/php form, which get passed to our mySQL database) to automatically join the other raffle (the foreign form).

Is there a way to pass the data on to them without having access to their database but through their form?

This is the foreign registration site: https://www.myopelservice.com/de/Raffle/RaffleRegistration.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as their form isn't setup to prevent requests from external sites, you can effectively post to their form using either [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or, if your PHP setup allows it (see the notes on the PHP manual page), [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

There's examples in the answers to this question here: [Submit form on one server, process it and then post results to another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939156/submit-form-on-one-server-process-it-and-then-post-results-to-another-domain).

The main thing is going to be making sure your post data matches what the other form is expecting.